# changin style of active status of CMenu in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to change the style of active status of menu in Yii. I got the documents from yii but it is not so well written. Can someone please help me out for this. Anyhelp will be highly appriciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your main.css file.  You should find a section like:

```
#mainmenu ul li a:hover, #mainmenu ul li.active a
{
//make it look how you want here

}
```

Comment: fyi, you can change the id and class names when you define the menu: `$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(     'id'=>'main_nav', 'activeCssClass'=>'active',     'items'=>array([items here...]`

Comment: @All - Why can't Yii simple use the :active pseudo class ?